# What is the point of exit() after each if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, exit

I've seen some php scripts that has exit() after each if statement. example:

```
if (empty($username)) {
   echo "error username is invalid";
  exit();
} else if (empty($password)) {
   echo "error password is invalid";
  exit();
} else {
  login($username, $password);
}

function login($u, $p)
{
   //do something here
   exit();
}
```

Comment: That depends on the script and cannot be generalized.

Comment: so above script would do better with or without the exit()'s?

Comment: It would do better with some context.

Comment: `exit()` is mostly used after something like `header('Location: index.php')`  to prevent the script from executing anything after that point

Comment: Above script should be changed to functions in a class, though it is impossible to help appropriate with the few lines of code you have posted.

Comment: far too general a question... using `exit()` after all `if()` would break many scripts

Comment: i get the general idea! thank you. :)

Comment: an exit() after every statement is correct syntax, but it complicates the maintenance of your code. So, don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is an absolutely pointless use of `exit()`. If you absolutely need one, just put it at the end of the script. Using `exit()` like that is only useful if you provide an [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) (used in command line applications).

Answer (score 1):

It 'works' for the purpose of the script but definitely not a good way of exiting scripts when error conditions occur. It will still output http status code 200.

exit is handy after a header relocation, or when debugging

Answer (score 0):

You can place the if statement in a function and you can use return on each case. So, you don't need to use else statements.
Example.

```
<?php
function foo() {
    if ($cond1) {
        return $result1;
    }
    if ($cond2) {
        return $result2;
    }
    if ($cond3) {
        return $result3;
    }
    if ($cond4) {
        return $result4;
    }
}
```